# How to filter entries by multiple checkbox field types

Tags: filter, checkboxes

I've set up checkbox fields for photos in a photo gallery called "photoColor", "photoSubject", and "photoSize", all of which contain a bunch of options.

On the gallery page I have filters and I'm using Ajax to update the page when a checkbox is clicked.

```
<div id="filters">
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="red" /> Red
 <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="green" /> Green

 <input type="checkbox" name="subjects[]" value="human" /> Human
 <input type="checkbox" name="subjects[]" value="animal" /> Animal

 <input type="checkbox" name="sizes[]" value="small" /> Small
 <input type="checkbox" name="sizes[]" value="large" /> Large
</div>
```

I'm gathering the values of the checkboxes like this

```
  var colors = [], subjects = [], sizes = [];
  $('input[name="colors[]"]:checked').each(function() {
     colors.push($(this).val());
  });

  $('input[name="subjects[]"]:checked').each(function() {
     subjects.push($(this).val());
  });

  $('input[name="sizes[]"]:checked').each(function() {
     sizes.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Right now I can filter for one option of one field type, i.e. this works:

```
{%  set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").photoColor(value) %}
```

(where value = "red" for example)

But I'm struggling to figure out how to write the query to combine ALL 3 field types in an "or" query, i.e. the results only need to match one of those properties, not all of them.

In other words, if a user checks off red, green, animal, and small, it will show all the results matching either red, green, animal, OR small - not just red/green animals that are small.

In pseudo code, it would be something like:

```
{% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery")
  where .photoColor is red or green
   or .photoSubject is animal
   or .photoSize is small
%}
```

I've been searching StackExchange and trying things I saw in other answers for days, but none of the situations were quite like mine, so I haven't been able to get it to work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the 'colours', 'subjects' and 'sizes' categories in Craft?

Comment: No, they are just set up as checkbox fields. I haven't used the category field type yet. I just looked at it. I'm not sure how to add all the values like I did with the checkbox fields. I"ll have to look into the documentation on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if I’ve misunderstood your question and over-simplified things, but wouldn’t the search() method give you precisely what you need?

As in:

```
{% set valsToFind = "field_photoColor:red OR field_photoColor:green OR field_photoSubject:animal OR field_photoSize:small" %}
{% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").search(valsToFind).all() %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't return any results. Even if I simplify it to just one field, i.e. {% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").search("field_photoColor:red") %} there still aren't any results.

Comment: Try just "red" as in {% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").search("red").all() %}

Comment: That was it, I needed to structure the query like this:  {% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").search("red OR green OR animal OR large").  Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked.

Looking at the code in the light of day, the field names are probably wrong.
{% set galleries = craft.entries.section("gallery").search("photoColor:red") %}
should also work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you there.

```
{% set galleries = craft.entries
    .section("gallery")
    .where([
        'or',
        {'field_photoColor'   : 'red' },
        {'field_photoColor'   : 'green' },
        {'field_photoSubject' : 'animal' },
        {'field_photoSize'    : 'small' }
    ])
%}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not returning any results. I tried with an easy example using only one field, photoColor.

Comment: Then it's likely you have a misnamed field or typo some where in your implementation, because that code queries data from entries in exactly the way you're looking for.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I double checked all the handles, they're all correct.